# navabar dropdown menu can't be closed

Tags: php, html, css, drop-down-menu, navbar

I have a navbar with a dropdown menu, but he is open by default, and can't be closed. I read my code multiple times and I can't find the mistake. Thanks for helping

```
<ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="Accueil.php">Accueil
        <span class="visually-hidden">(current)</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="PrendreRDV.php">Plannifier un rendez-vous</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="AfficherRDV.php">Afficher les rendez-vous</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" target="_blank" onclick="return confirm('Vous allez être redirigé vers une autre page')"  href="https://calendly.com/app/scheduled_events/user/me">Gérer un rendez-vous</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="AfficherClients.php">Gérer clients</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="Calendrier.php">Agenda</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="Historique.php">Historique</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Administration</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu show" data-bs-popper="none">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Modifier champs</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Modifier table</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Modifier client</a>
      </div>
    </li>
 
  </ul>
```

Comment: We can't really help without any CSS or JavaScript but if you want your submenus to be hidden by default just apply a `display: none` to those elements and toggle with an `active` class in JS. + I see you using a `target="_blank"` here is a link for you [target blank correct html](https://css-tricks.com/use-target_blank/#aa-correct-html)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add Css & Javascript to get that funtionality.